# Inequality $a,b,c > 0 \Rightarrow \frac{b+c}{\sqrt{a^2 + bc}} + \frac{a+c}{\sqrt{b^2 + ac}} + \frac{a+b}{\sqrt{c^2 + ab}} \geq 4$

Tags: inequality, radicals, fractions, holder-inequality

Prove:
$a,b,c > 0 \Rightarrow \frac{b+c}{\sqrt{a^2 + bc}} + \frac{a+c}{\sqrt{b^2 + ac}} + \frac{a+b}{\sqrt{c^2 + ab}} \geq 4$

I was able to obtain a loose bound. My method:
\begin{align}
\frac{b+c}{\sqrt{a^2 + bc}} + \frac{a+c}{\sqrt{b^2 + ac}} + \frac{a+b}{\sqrt{c^2 + ab}} &\geq 3\left(\frac{(b+c)(a+c)(a+b)}{\sqrt{(a^2 + bc)(b^2 + ac)(c^2 + ab)}}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \\
 &> 3\cdot2^{\frac{1}{3}} \sim 3.78
\end{align}
The first step follows from the AM-GM inequality. The second step follows from the inequality: $4(a^2+bc)(b^2+ac)(c^2+ab) \leq [(b+c)(a+c)(b+a)]^2 $ which is an inequality which has been asked as a question previously. (I am unable to find it's link somehow). Also the second step has a '$>$' instead of a '$\geq$' because both inequalities do not hold simultaneously.

How to prove the tight bound?

[I had tried Jensen's inequality to $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ and C-S, but it didn't help.]

Comment: possible minimum is $3\sqrt2$, when $a=b=c$.

Comment: $3\sqrt{2} > 4$.

Comment: So it's not contradictory, but if you were trying to give a tight lower bound, then how would you prove it?

Comment: Similar problem. https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2001_IMO_Shortlist_Problems/A6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By Holder and Schur
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{b+c}{\sqrt{a^2+bc}}=\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{b+c}{\sqrt{a^2+bc}}\right)^2\sum\limits_{cyc}(b+c)(a^2+bc)}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(b+c)(a^2+bc)}}\geq$$
$$\geq\sqrt{\frac{\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}(b+c)\right)^3}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(b+c)(a^2+bc)}}=\sqrt{\frac{8(a+b+c)^3}{2\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)}}=$$
$$=2\sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3+3a^2b+3a^2c+2abc)}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)}}\geq2\sqrt{\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(4a^2b+4a^2c+abc)}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^2b+a^2c)}}\geq4.$$
I used the following Schur.

For positives $a$, $b$ and $c$ prove that
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b-a^2c+abc)\geq0.$$
In our case
$$\sum_{cyc}(a^3+3a^2b+3a^2c+2abc)=$$
$$=\sum_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b-a^2c+abc+4a^2b+4a^2c+abc)\geq$$
$$\geq\sum_{cyc}(4a^2b+4a^2c+abc).$$

Comment: It took me a good 30 minutes to understand the maths here. I am a little confused how the second last step is obtained: i.e. how is:
$a^3 + 3a^2b + 3a^2c + 2abc \geq 4a^2b + 4a^2c + abc $.
And if in the last step, you have used $abc > 0$, then isn't the bound supposed to be '$>$' there?

Comment: I used Schur: $\sum\limits_{cyc}(a^3-a^2b-a^2c+abc)\geq0.$ About your  second question. If $abc>0$ then $abc\geq0.$ Just the equality in your inequality does not occur.

Comment: So that would mean that the lower bound 4 is not tight either. I was confused about this earlier. Thanks for the help!